# How to get values from pixel information bar on the image editor using blender python

Tags: python, uv-image-editor

Does anyone know how to get these value from the pixel information bar below and have them save in text file using blender python?

[image]

Comment: The information are the X and Y coordinates of the pixel, Z is the depth at the pixel. The RGBA are the color and alpha of the pixel, followed by the display transformed values in RGB and HSV and the Luminance. You can't directly access the output produce by `ED_image_draw_info()`, but you could get the information from the render image and its passes.

Comment: @RobertGützkow thank you for the explanation. Do you know how to get the information from the render image using blender python? And what do you mean by "passes"?

Comment: It's not straight forward: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2170/how-to-access-render-result-pixels-from-python-script

Comment: @RobertGützkow Thank you! This link is really helping. I also found other script that gives similar output. You can find it here:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35191/how-to-get-color-and-z-depth-from-viewer-node/71264