# How to get luminance value of every pixel from the rendered image?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-layers

This link below shows how to get value of RGB color and z-depth from viewer node, that corresponding to the value on the pixel information bar (figure below).

Link :
[How to get Color and Z-Depth from Viewer Node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35191/how-to-get-color-and-z-depth-from-viewer-node/71264)

Question is, how do I get the value of the Luminance of every pixel from the rendered image that is corresponding to the luminance value on the pixel information bar? Can I get the luminance value from the viewer node too, same method like the link? Do I need to use additional nodes to get that value?

[image: pixel information bar of rendered image]
Thank you for help in advance!